# Rearranging photos for time lapse

Tags: timelapse

My camera has 2 camera slots and I have captured a lot of images. Now when I put them into one folder they are not in the order they were taken. I am using Time Lapse Assembler. How can I make sure that images are assembled correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many image applications allow you to sort files in a folder based on one of several different paramaters. File name is one such paramater. Shooting date/time is another. Once you have them arranged *within the application* in the order they were taken the application should also have a batch renaming tool that will allow you to rename the files based on the naming conventions you select. Select a beginning file number and tell it to rename them in sequence. I do this all the time with Canon's *Digital Photo Professional* when combining images of an event shot with more than one camera body. I just have to confirm the internal clocks in both cameras are synchronized before the shoot. I use Canon's *EOS Utility* to automatically set the clock in each camera to match the clock in my PC.

Comment: thank, While capturing clouds or night time. What interval should i put. I use 10 sec but not much of 'wow' factor

Comment: The interval depends on several factors: what is the planned frame rate of the finished project. How fast are the environmental changes? How much do you want to compress time? An entire night into 30 seconds or an hour into 5 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

What is the settings in camera for file naming?

Do you have it continuous or every folder starts with 00001?

If numbers starts from 1 in every folder, then simply change settings in the camera.
But I suppose Time Lapse assembler should have some kind of sort functionality (by date), but I have never used it, so I cannot guarantee.

Another option:
put all of the files in one folder, sort by date taken and rename the files. 
There are multiple ways how you can rename them all at once. Simplest is to select all files and rename to lets say picture. The names will be picture.jpg, picture (2).jpg etc
Another way - using special software for renaming or using dos or powershell comands.

Comment: its the default.

Comment: you mean default that starts with 1 every time?

Comment: What "default" means depends on what "my camera" means.